# program crashing on assembler (arrays and loops)

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, masm

well, my program works in a following way: it makes and array, then makes a loop which finds the quantity of numbers which divide on operand m without a leftover.

The code assembles, but running the exe file makes the masm64 ruin

```
include \masm64\include64\masm64rt.inc
.data        
mas dq 2,5,8
m dq 2
res dq 0
title1 db "Решение уравнения. masm64",0
txt1 db "Уравнение с массивом",10,
"Количесвто чисел, которые делятся на %d без остатка:%d",10,10,
"Автор:Тарадай Святослав",0                              
buf1 dq 3 dup(0),0                                          
.code                             
entry_point proc
mov rax,3
mov rbx,0
mov rcx,mas
main:
add rcx,1
xor rdx,rdx
div m
cmp rdx,0
jz yes
jnz no
cmp rcx,rax
je done
yes:
add rbx,1
jmp main
no: jmp main
done:
mov res,rbx
invoke wsprintf,ADDR buf1,ADDR txt1,m,res
invoke MessageBox,0,ADDR buf1,ADDR title1,MB_ICONINFORMATION 
invoke ExitProcess,0
entry_point endp         
end
```

can you please say what's up with this one? i'll be happy to hear anything about this one

Comment: Your loop never ends, as the two instructions (before the `yes:` label) will never execute because the `z` flag is either set (`jz`) or not set (`jnz`).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm , thanks for the answer. then how can i fix it? i think i can delete the jnz part,but this doesn't fix the crush

Comment: Don't use `div` to divide by a constant `2`, just check the low bit of RAX with `test al, 1` / `jnz odd_number`